# ubuntu 22.04.1 require GPT parttion scheme for insttallation

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi, mbr

i'm trying to dual boot ubuntu 22.04.1 and my windows 10 but when i try to install ubuntu it require me using GPT parttion scheme, but my windows 10 is using MBR and my BIOS running in legacy mode so i dont know if ubuntu 22.04.1 still support MBR?

Comment: Ubuntu does support MBR. It is unclear what is the problem. If you boot Ubuntu LiveUSB in a legacy mode, it will install easily. Ubuntu can be installed in UEFI mode too on MBR.

Comment: I used rufus and select MBR scheme to create usb boot, but when i boot into usb and using try ubuntu, i checked bios mode i saw ubuntu on usb running in uefi, i dont know why?

Comment: It doesn't matter what you selected to create a LiveUSB. You an always boot in legacy mode using bios menu if bios allows it. BTW I am writing from Ubuntu 22.04 installed on MBR.

Comment: Microsoft has required vendors to install Windows in UEFI/gpt since Windows 8 released. If system is that old you may want a lighter weight flavor of Ubuntu. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie

Comment: Some machines allow booting in both modes, with one preferred.  The Ubuntu install media has both boot methods, so maybe your machine is set to prefer UEFI over MSDOS (and your hard disk has no UEFI partition, so MSDOS is used).  Change the preference in the BIOS/UEFI settings. Also, MDSOS partitioning only allows 4 primary partitions.  The Ubuntu install may go into an extended partition on logical partitions (extended is counted as a primary, but allow sub-partitions).

Comment: The same thing i had in Ubuntu 20.10 even system was boot in bios mode i get this stupid error about gpt and uefi filesystem.. Maybe bootoption noefi can help.